# How to save selected Suggested Route from Google Map Api to db for later view

Tags: c#, asp-classic

I've been trying to save selected Google Map Api alternative Suggested Route to db. Extracting that selected route and grabbing it is being confusing. I just want to save one of routes from provideRouteAlternatives and view them later. Thanks

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests

Comment: What is your question? Maybe if you had a code example, of how your tried to store it in the DB.

Comment: You can use jquery to get json from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=75+9th+Ave+New+York,+NY&destination=MetLife+Stadium+1+MetLife+Stadium+Dr+East+Rutherford,+NJ+07073&key=YOUR_API_KEY And then you can make post ajax with values from json to your backend and save it into db.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-)
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)